# Function to convert char(255) non standard dates into timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-function, postgresql-10

I have database with a column of date strings that are in the format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.3nZ`
I would like to transform them into TIMESTAMP so that I can then apply the BETWEEN function to identify rows that fall in a given time window (this being the ultimate goal of the exercise).
I can't just change the nature of the column unfortunately.
What is the best way to achieve this?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: 3 digits for seconds, really _sss_?

Comment: Yeah, I know! Unfortunately the DB is not in my control. I've filed some "bugs" with the owners to "fix" all this

Comment: Are any second values > 59? Show us some sample table data and the expected result. What do you expect for `1999-12-31T23.59.321Z`

Comment: So what does an example time look like? Do they all have leading zeroes or trailing zeroes to pad out the three digits?

Comment: So following your edit it has two digit seconds and then three digits for miliseconds

Comment: yeah, and that is not in `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:sssZ` format as stated

Comment: That string can be cast directly: `'2021-01-28T10:26:32.359Z'::timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    to_timestamp('2021-01-28T10:26:32.359Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') t
FROM
    dual;
```